# What does 'dens of political patronage' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Public administrators tend to rouse attention only when complaints
>   flare over their competence or their fees or their tendency to oversee
>   **dens of political patronage**. Or when they run afoul of the law. Last
>   year, a former longtime counsel to the Bronx County public
>   administrator pleaded guilty to grand larceny, while a bookkeeper for
>   the Kings County public administrator was sentenced to a prison term
>   for stealing from the dead.

[The Lonely Death of George Bell](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/18/nyregion/dying-alone-in-new-york-city.html?_r=0)

What does '**dens of political patronage**' mean?

Comment: Please check [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dens-of-political-patronage.3084408/)

Comment: @ Peter  Thank you very much. Do you mind posting an answer so that I could wrap up my question?

Comment: I'd say that a "den" of "political patronage" is even more egregious than an instance of "political patronage." A "den" would refer to a system of political patronage with multiple layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Political patronage** occurs when a politician **exchanges favours for support** (read: money).

> You back me and I'll get that law passed for you

Such practices are usually considered **corrupt and unlawful**

**Dens of political patronage** is a metaphor for the systematic and widespread practice of **favours for sale**, each department being its own ***den***

The phrase is also an allusion to the **Den of Thieves** story in the Bible where Jesus chases **the money changers** (considered a dirty practice) from the Temple (a holy place).  The money changers had turned the Temple into a **Den of Thieves**

Answer (score 1):

When I read this phrase I think of people in government who use their position to help someone achieve a goal and in turn expect to be
compensated.

A den is the home of a wild animal,particulularly a beast of prey. It also has the meaning of a cavern or hollow used as a place of concealment. So you may see such phrases as a "den of robbers" or a "den of vipers"

A patron is someone who takes care of you as in a patron saint or an artist's patron. So patronage is taking care of someone but in the case of political patronage something is expected in return.